# Lock down Windows 8 to run only one app

Tags: windows-8, tablet, restrictions

I am looking to lock down/restrict a Windows 8 tablet to run only one app. The tablet will be used as a remote control for a networked audio system (via a dedicated wifi network with no internet access).

Ideally I want to make this as foolproof as possible, so that any person at the venue can only access the one application, and not accidentally 'mess up' or 'get lost' in Windows. However I also want to retain the ability to make changes to the system myself (or indeed anyone else working on my behalf).

My thoughts are to create two user accounts: an Administrator (password-protected) account and an End-User account (not password-protected). I am looking for a way to force the audio system app to start as soon as the End-User is signed in, and also for a way to make the Start button function purely to turn the screen on. I figured that I can set the audio app to run fullscreen and always on top by default, this should remove the possibility of closing the app and accessing the desktop, right?

Regarding the Start button, could I just unpin all other apps from the Start menu other than the audio remote app, or is there still a way to navigate to the desktop or other system settings from here?

I am open to any and all suggestions, though this is my first time using Windows 8 and the deadline is close, so it is slightly a baptism of fire! The tablet is an Acer Iconia W3-810 by the way.

Many thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 4):

A quick google search turned up a feature in Windows 8.1 called kiosk mode which will lock the windows into a single app. I don't believe this feature to be in windows 8, so you might have to upgrade to 8.1, which is a free upgrade, but might cause incompatibility with some software that you are running.

Here is an article about kiosk mode:

http://www.geek.com/microsoft/windows-8-1-kiosk-mode-locks-systems-to-a-single-app-1552963/

edit: one thing to note is that the "hot corners" is still enabled in kiosk mode. You can disable multitasking with apps in the metro settings app. (so that you can't swipe in from the left and select another app)